# Sitecore Tracker.Current is not initialized

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm having this issue related with Tracker.

```
[InvalidOperationException: Tracker.Current is not initialized]
   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args) +304
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartAnalyticsPipeline.Run() +293
   Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.MvcEvents.RequestBegin.StartTracking.Process(RequestBeginArgs args) +139
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
   Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +74
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +923
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157
```

In the web.config I've the

> enableTracking="true"

If I set to false it works but there's no Tracking

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use? do you have both `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` settings set to true (check `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`)?. Does your license supports xDB?

Comment: Where are you calling the code - is it in an MVC Controller or code that was called via an MVC controller?

Comment: Are you using mvc or webforms? Are you requesting a Sitecore page or some custom page? Sitecore will normally instantiate / initialize the tracker when u call a Sitecore page, but if you are viewing a non Sitecore mvc routed page u might be missing the Sitecore pipelines that normally run. We need more information to help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was looking at the problem and it was related with my custom ContactFacets.config that was not correct.

Unfortunately the error warning is not so much conclusive.

Comment: @Younes, I have had same problem, I was using latest version of sitecore (Sitecore 8.2 rev. 170728 (exe)), when I created new custom home page item and created new layout in vs2017, then published them, to preview it, the error message is show as above.

Comment: Did you run Mongo instance? Did you add @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() in <head> of your layout?

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple factors that can contribute to the issue you are experiencing.
To simplify and summarize comments given previously, you need to be sure that:

1. MongoDB is running
2. Your Connection Strings properly set
3. Sitecore License has xDB added
4. Xdb.Enabled and Xdb.Tracking.Enabled are both set to "true"
5. Analytics.ClusterName in Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config is a proper hostname
6. Verify you have VisitorIdentification tag added (to weed out robots)

Comment: And another: you aren't trying to access the tracker before its been initialized e.g. in httpRequestBegin pipeline, the tracker hasn't been started

Answer (score 3):

The first thing we need to check is to make sure Mongo DB is installed and Mongo DB service is started.This fixed the issue on my machine.

Comment: Yes, everything is running without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most recently, I had my Mongo DB running in a Docker Container and Docker wasn't running and so, Mongo DB wasn't running either... when the container was started, the issue was resolved.... Just a variation of the fact that a running MongoDB solves the issue!